# richfaces filtering date column

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I made filter for column that contains String values. It works. But the same approach doesn't work
for date. When I choose some date it doesn't filter anything, but when I choose empty value in filter it show all dates. So it works, but something wrong with dates:(

There is code for string values:

```
    <rich:column filterValue="#{clientBean.confirmFilter}"
                 filterExpression="#{fn:containsIgnoreCase(client.conferm,
 clientBean.confirmFilter)}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:panelGroup>
                            <h:outputText value="Filter " />
                            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{clientBean.confirmFilter}">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{clientBean.listConfirmFilter}" />
                                <a4j:ajax render="table" execute="@this" event="change" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{clientBean.getConfirmValue(client.conferm)}" />  
                </rich:column>
```

Code for dates:

```
    <rich:column filterValue="#{clientBean.dataOpenFilter}"
                 filterExpression="#{fn:containsIgnoreCase(client.dataOpen, 
clientBean.dataOpenFilter)}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:panelGroup>
                             <a4j:outputPanel layout="block"> 
                                <rich:calendar value="#{clientBean.dataOpenFilter}" locale="ru/RU" 
                                    popup="true" datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy" 
                                    showApplyButton="false" cellWidth="24px" cellHeight="22px"   
                                    disabled="false"  > 
                                <a4j:ajax render="table" execute="@this" event="change" />
                                </rich:calendar> 
                            </a4j:outputPanel>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{client.dataOpen}" locale="ru/RU" >
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </rich:column>
```

And my managedBean:

```
private String confirmFilter;
    private List<SelectItem> listConfirmFilter;
    private Date dataOpenFilter;
    ...

    public String getConfirmFilter() {
        return confirmFilter;
    }

    public void setConfirmFilter(String confirmFilter) {
        this.confirmFilter = confirmFilter;
    } 

    public List<SelectItem> getListConfirmFilter() {
        listConfirmFilter = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        listConfirmFilter.add(new SelectItem("",""));
        listConfirmFilter.add(new SelectItem("N","Not confirmed"));
        listConfirmFilter.add(new SelectItem("Y","Confirmed"));
        return listConfirmFilter;
    }

    public Date getDataOpenFilter() {
        return dataOpenFilter;
    }

    public void setDataOpenFilter(Date dataOpenFilter) {
        this.dataOpenFilter = dataOpenFilter;
    }
```

I worked out this:

```
public Filter<Client> getDateOpenFilterImpl() {
            return new Filter<Client>() {
                public boolean accept(Client client) {
                    Date dataOpenFilter = getDataOpenFilter();
                    if (dataOpenFilter == null ||  
                                    dataOpenFilter.compareTo((Date)client.getDataOpen())==0) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };
     }

<rich:column filter="#{clientBean.dateOpenFilterImpl}" ...
```

Comment: You are trying to filter by `Date` using a method you made to filter by `String`? `fn:containsIgnoreCase(client.dataOpen, 
clientBean.dataOpenFilter)`

Comment: I put the comment as an answer so this question can have an accepted answer. Please accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to filter by `Date` using a method made to filter by `String`:

`fn:containsIgnoreCase(client.dataOpen, clientBean.dataOpenFilter)`

Comment: Thanks. Yes you are right. I wrote at the top of how to resolve the problem.